# How can I append a value to a dictionary key with multiple "values"?

Tags: python

For example:

```
mydict = {'Jan':[1,2,3]}
```

How can I add another value to that key?
I tried the update method but that just overwrites the entire key.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: `mydict['Jan'].append(4)`

Comment: no effort to look at the docs? the value is a `list` so list methods come in to play --> like using [append](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: It may be misleading to think of it as "adding another value [to the key-value pair]". Currently, the key-value pair has exactly one value: a list with three elements. If you want to end up with `{'Jan':[1,2,3,4]}`, that _also_ has exactly one value. In general, you can't have a dict that has one key and two values.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mydict['Jan'].append('value')
```